# Travelling across a table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying a table and letting the user click on a particular cell in this table. When the user clicks on a particular cell, I highlight it. 
Next I am trying to mobilize the arrow keys on the keyboard. i.e

when user presses "right-arrow" key .. the next cell should get highlighted and if the user presses "top-arrow" key.. the cell above the current one should get selected.

I believe you guys get the flow.

This is excel like functionality.

I am almost there but not yet.. any anyone point me in the right direction.

My plnkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hahh4uyQ130zOS8noC3D

Answer (score 0):

I would create a directive watching a model value object called 'selected'. Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in body">
    <td ng-repeat="h in header"
        my-cell="selected"
        row="{{$parent.$index}}"
        col="{{$index}}"
        style="width:{{element.width}}px">{{element[h.column]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

## **UPDATE**

The issue around the above solution is that ng-repeat has isolated scope for each $index entry it is in so changes in $scope.select were not being seen by other cells. To get around this I used $emit and $on events, look at: http://plnkr.co/edit/CS21gUe3arstrgubnpTr?p=preview

```
angular.module("CustomTable").directive("selectMe", function($rootScope) {
  return ({
    restrict: "A",
    link: link,
    require: "^customTable"
  });

  function link(scope, element, attributes, ctCtrl) {
    var selected,
        mkEvent = function(r,c) {
          scope.$emit('selectMeEvent',{
            row: r,
            col: c
          });
        }

    element.on('click', function(e) {
      mkEvent(attributes.row,attributes.col);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('selectMeEvent',function(e,sObj) {
      (sObj.row === attributes.row &&
       sObj.col === attributes.col) ? 
       element.addClass('highlight-me') : 
       element.removeClass('highlight-me');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @koolunix..tried out your solution .. I beliebe the watch part of it doesn't work as expected .. take a look at the plnkr here. The directive is in the file selectMe.js http://plnkr.co/edit/yf7Ywfj9RjDuaDnOx6DL

Comment: Your plunker link does not exist- are you sure you saved it?